# API Limit consumption from Apex into the org

Tags: api, limits

Have any of you figured out the usage of API Limits (per 24-hour interval) when using Apex back into the org?

Let's say something that uses `System.URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm()` as domain to call an SFDC REST resource not yet available in Apex, using standard Apex `HttpRequest` (some resources from [Connect REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_what_is_chatter_connect.htm) for instance).

I have tried to use the report "API Calls Made Within Last 7 Days", but I cannot find a definitive answer.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_limits.htm works for many limits.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current usage with:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(new Url(Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl(), '/services/data/v55.0/limits').toExternalForm());
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
Map<String, Object> values = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
Map<String, Object> dailyLimits = (Map<String, Object>)values.get('DailyApiRequests');
Integer maxCallPerDay = (Integer)dailyLimits.get('Max');
Integer remainingCallsForToday = (Integer)dailyLimits.get('Remaining');
System.debug(remainingCallsForToday);
```

You can see the full list of available properties in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_limits.htm).

Comment: Great reminder, thanks sfdcfox. So, the one million dollar question is: does this call to limits API counts into the limits? I will test but I guess so.

Comment: @JefersonChaves unfortunately, yes. Make sure you use it sparingly.

Comment: You are awesome sfdcfox!